# Displaying the correct condition found in WHERE clause

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables that have the same columns. If a change occurs it is being recorded in `table2` and then I compare `table1` to `table2` and see if they are different. If they are different I conclude there was a change and I would like to display that in my resulting table.

For example:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.age, t1.profession, column_changed, old_value, new_value
FROM   table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE  t1.column1<>t2.column1 
    OR t1.column2<>t2.column2 
    OR t1.column3<>t2.column3
```

Of course this query isn't correct. I would like the `column_changed`, `old_value`, `new_value` display the relevant values.

Any ideas?

Comment: How does table1 get updated? Please provide some test data/scenarios to help us understand.

Comment: I don't think that is relevant. If I am mistaken please explain why.

Comment: yep, I re-read your question. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further brain storming this I have concluded that ganders solution works better with slight improvment. The improvement is a while loop and a count variable. We need to have that in case there are several columns changed at once and not just one. It will, however, result in outputting NULL's as well so you can just delete them. Here is the modified query:

```
WHILE @count<3
BEGIN
  Select t1.name, t1.age, t1.profession,     
    case when t1.column1 <> t2.column1 and @count = 1 then 'column1 changed'         
      when t1.column2 <> t2.column2 @count = 2 then 'column2 changed'         
      -- and so on...         
    end as [column_changed],     
    case when t1.column1 <> t2.column1 @count = 1 then t1.column1         
      when t1.column2 <> t2.column2 @count = 2 then t1.column2         
      -- and so on...         
    end as [old_value],     
    case when t1.column1 <> t2.column1 @count = 1 then t2.column1         
      when t1.column2 <> t2.column2 @count = 2 then t2.column2         
      -- and so on...         
    end as [new_value] 
  From table1 t1, table2 t2 
  Where t1.column1 <> t2.column1 Or t1.column2 <> t2.column2 Or t1.column3 <> t2.column3 
  SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Does Age, name, profession form a primary key (or at least a unique key?):

If so, you could do something like:

```
SELECT 
  t1.name, t1.age, t1.profession, 
  t1.column1 as t1column1, t2.column1 as t2column1, 
  t1.column2 as t1column2, t2.column2 as t2column2, 
FROM   
  table1 t1, table2 t2 
WHERE 
  (t1.name = t2.name and t1.age = t2.age and t1.profession = t2.profession) and
  (
   t1.column1<>t2.column1      
   OR t1.column2<>t2.column2     
   OR t1.column3<>t2.column3)
```

Of course, that requires a unique key which is the same across both tables.  Also, I clearly changed the results of the query to show all columns instead of just the one that changed.  Identifying the one that changed like that in a single T-SQL Query is awkward (but possible) so my recommendation would be to return it like this and depending on your use case have the application/presentation layer handle finding which column changed or just scan it by eye.

If you really want to do it in T-SQL, you could do it with UNIONS, like:

```
SELECT 
  t1.name, t1.age, t1.profession, 
  'column1' as ColumnChanged,
  t1.column1 as oldValue,
  t2.column1 as newValue
FROM   
  table1 t1, table2 t2 
WHERE 
  (t1.name = t2.name and t1.age = t2.age and t1.profession = t2.profession) and
   t1.column1<>t2.column1  
UNION ALL #better peformance than UNION, which would enforce uniqueness
SELECT 
  t1.name, t1.age, t1.profession, 
  'column2' as ColumnChanged,
  t1.column2 as oldValue,
  t2.column2 as newValue
FROM   
  table1 t1, table2 t2 
WHERE 
  (t1.name = t2.name and t1.age = t2.age and t1.profession = t2.profession) and
   t1.column2<>t2.column2 
.......
```

Comment: case statements allow this to be accomplished without having to do unions with multiple select statements.

Comment: You are right, but there are two reasons I would not go with using case statements.  The first is that it will only give you the first column changed if more than one columnn has changed.  UNIONS will give you all the changes.  The second is that, in my personal opinion, they are harder to read than the UNION (although it could be shorter).  Also, unless you want to look at the ColumnX's for every row against every row, you still need a unique key comparison in there somewhere...

Comment: You are quite right. I thought of using CASE statements, but to have all the changes (if two columns changed and not one) would require multiple nested CASE's so maybe UNION ALL is better here.

Comment: I just thought of a problem: If you are monetoring 3 columns (if two of them changed then I need to display both changes) then it's enough to have 2^3=8 SELECT statements and UNION ALL between them. But what if you have 6 columns to monitor. You would need 2^6=64 SELECT statements. Is there a shorter way? Makes me sad to think that I have to write so many SELECT statements.

Comment: I would do it in the presentation layer where I could take advantage of a wider variety of data structures for the comparisons.  But, if you want to do it in pure sql, you could use dynamic SQL to create the select statements for you.  Its not the same thing, but I use a similar concept at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Search/64877/

Comment: I tried going to that link, but it requires regestration. I don't want to do that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think I still have the original word doc if you would like me to email it to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12277/discussion-between-paul-kar-and-timothyawiseman)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select t1.name, t1.age, t1.profession,
    case when t1.column1 <> t2.column1 then 'column1 changed'
        when t1.column2 <> t2.column2 then 'column2 changed'
        -- and so on...
        end as [column_changed],
    case when t1.column1 <> t2.column1 then t1.column1
        when t1.column2 <> t2.column2 then t1.column2
        -- and so on...
        end as [old_value],
    case when t1.column1 <> t2.column1 then t2.column1
        when t1.column2 <> t2.column2 then t2.column2
        -- and so on...
        end as [new_value]
From table1 t1, table2 t2
Where t1.column1 <> t2.column1
Or t1.column2 <> t2.column2
Or t1.column3 <> t2.column3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your solution rewritten as a single SELECT statement (or, if you like, @ganders's rewritten to support several changes in the same row):

```
SELECT
  x.column_changed,
  t1.column1 AS old_value,
  t2.column1 AS new_value
FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'column1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'column2' UNION ALL
    …
  ) x (column_changed) ON (
    x.column_changed = 'column1' AND t1.column1 <> t2.column1 OR
    x.column_changed = 'column2' AND t1.column2 <> t2.column2 OR
    …
  )
```

Comment: You don't think it's more complicated then the case statements?

Comment: As a matter of fact, no, I don't think this is more complicated than using two CASE expressions like in your solution. But even if I did, that wasn't my point. I just wanted to suggest a solution that used a purely set-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

I added a **join @T2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name** to your query using the **name** column. Making the assumption that it can be used to link the records between the two tables.

```
select 
    t1.name, t1.age, t1.profession,
    column_change =
        case when t1.column1 <> t2.column1 then 'column1'
             when t1.column2 <> t2.column2 then 'column2'
             when t1.column3 <> t2.column3 then 'column3'
      end,
   old_value =
        case when t1.column1 <> t2.column1 then t1.column1
             when t1.column2 <> t2.column2 then t1.column2
             when t1.column3 <> t2.column3 then t1.column3
      end,
    new_value = 
        case when t1.column1 <> t2.column1 then t2.column1
             when t1.column2 <> t2.column2 then t2.column2
             when t1.column3 <> t2.column3 then t2.column3
        end
from @T1 t1
    join @T2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name
where 
    (t1.column1 <> t2.column1
    or t1.column2 <> t2.column2
    or t1.column3 <> t2.column3)
```